# Postgres how can I work with csv file without copy it to the DB

Tags: postgresql, csv

What I do now is use COPY for the csv file I want to work with, then when I finish, I delete the table.

- `COPY mytable FROM 'D:/test.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS ','`
- do my work
- `drop table mytable`;

is there any other preferred/professional way

Comment: If you are doing that on a regular basis, then why do you drop the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what the work is, [the `file_fdw` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) may be suitable.  It lets you access a CSV file as if it was a table.

There are some major downsides to this, though: It's slow, and you can't create indexes on it. So it's often much better to just `COPY` into an `UNLOGGED` table, do the work, and drop the table.